# Why can't I select the code signing identity in XCode to validate the app

Tags: ios, distribution

really simple problem became a disaster =).
 I can't select the needed code signing identity in Xcode. Why is it so?? The certificates and the keys are ok. Here is picture:
[image]

Any ideas???

Comment: could you explain this problem better?  In the graphic you have attached, I see something is already selected.

Comment: When you're trying to submit the the app to the app store, you have to select two options: 1. The app name. 2. Code signing identity. I need the first item of the list of signing identities, but can't select it. That is the question - why I can't do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your certificate? Today I had same problem where I was unable to select `Code Signing Identity` after selecting `Provisioning Profile` and it turns out my certificate has expired.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your bundle Identifier . This is guess , but this may be the case. Your bundle identifier must match with your app Id. You can change bundle ID from the .plist file .

Comment: Thanks for quickness. I've double checked it, it's good, but I still can't select it